# Loop through columns, with almost identical names

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table, from where I must extract some datas.

There is columns that are the same, but except for one thing, the last past of the name, that is a number. I explain :

I got startDate and endDate several times made this way :

```
startDate1 | endDate1 |startDate2 | endDate2 |startDate3 | endDate3
```

etc...

And, I want to extract the data, one by one 
so startDate1 and endDate1 first, then startDate2 and endDate2...

So I made something like this :

```
 FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      IF reg.startDate ||i is not null THEN
--TODO
      END IF;
 END LOOP;
```

Reg is is a line on a cursor.

Of course, this doesn't work, because we can't concatenate like this (I got a statement ignored).

What I want if a loop, that will be the same as if I do this :

```
      IF reg.startDate1 is not null THEN
--TODO
      END IF;

      IF reg.startDate2 is not null THEN
--TODO
      END IF;         
      IF reg.startDate3 is not null THEN
--TODO
      END IF;
```

So, something like:

```
 FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      IF reg.startDate||i is not null THEN
--TODO
      END IF;
 END LOOP;
```

So i got this data, in DIFFERENT columns :

```
startDate1 | endDate1 |startDate2 | endDate2 |startDate3 | endDate3 

18/07/2013 | 19/07/2013 | 18/08/2013 | 19/08/2013 | 18/09/2013 | 19/09/2013
```

What I want is something like this :

```
FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      IF reg.startDate ||i is not null THEN
insert into table (date) values (reg.endDate |i);
      END IF;
 END LOOP;
```

Hear, I will insert 19/07/2013, 19/08/2013, 19/09/2013.

I really don't know what is unclear there.

Is this possible to do it with, or without a concatenation?

The question title maybe wrong, but I don't know how to ask it in one title other way.

Comment: Define "doesn't work, because we can't concatenate like this". Also, adding some example input data plus the expected output would help tremendously.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt well, I just want to get the datas using `reg.startDate||i` foreach column that start by startDate. I must, thanks to a loop, avoid the multiple if clause. What I do in todo does not affect the loop.

Comment: *Please* add sample input + expected output. It's totally unclear whether you have an input string containing all concatenated date values or something completely different.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I add somes samples, but I erally don't know what is unclear there. I got 6 different columns, containing dates. The column names are the same, except for the number at the end (1,2,3). And I want, foreach column that is like `startDate` make some work, if the date is different from null. As, the only difference is the number at the end of the name of the columns, I want avoid redondance.

Comment: The most sensible approach would be to change your data model and add a detail table for the dates. If that isn't feasible, the `UNION` approach proposed by @AndrzejReduta is the way to go.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I already got the datas in reg. Why is the AndrzejReduta answer more suitable while I got a lot of others data in my select query? If I can't loop, I will be easier to simply use reg.

Answer (score 0):

Use union

```
Select startDate1, endDate1 FROM YOURTable
UNION  
Select startDate2, endDate2 FROM YOURTable
UNION  
Select startDate3, endDate3 FROM YOURTable

...;
```

Comment: My datas are already in reg. Why should I redo a select query?

Comment: @Zaphod You should redo a select query because you want it to work. You're trying to make a relational language (SQL) work with improperly normalized data, so you should expect a query that doesn't look good nor work well. ("Work well" refers to the future maintenance of the code and potential poor performance, not to incorrect results.)

Comment: @user2338816 I don't understand your point. I make a query for a cursor `SELECT id, name, startDate1, startDate2, startDate3` . So I already got all the data registered. The question is, How can I avoid to write a block of code foreach startDate. It will be used only one time, the database will not change.

Comment: @Zaphod `How can I avoid to write a block of code foreach startDate.` You can't. It's possible that a block of code that uses dynamic SQL could be constructed to make it work with your original query idea, but it'd be significantly more complex than the @AndrzejReduta answer. It's a poorly designed row definition, and you're stuck with it. Code to process the rows will use ugly SELECTs.

Comment: @user2338816 so, I will simply use a if statement for my datas, that are in `reg` . Change the query is not relevant, if the result is just gettings the datas.